# How to handle 301 redirects for php variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've realized that some of my 301 redirects in my .htaccess don't work because of the PHP variables but having read multiple posts on here about how to overcome it I've come to the conclusion that I'm too thick to figure out the exact code I need to use.

If some genius could spell it out for me that would be awesome.

Here is an example of what's not working

```
Redirect 301 /detail.php?prod_id=100 http://www.domain.com/new-url/
```

Please let me know the exact code I need to make this work on apache. I have around 100 urls and each has a unique id.

UPDATE
Here is my existing full code from my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPDATE

OK that worked with my previous version of .htaccess but since I went live with my wordpress version of my site that code seems to kill my .htaccess file which has the standard wordpress info, how would I fit the above 301 code into this?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

QUERY_STRING canot be matched using `Redirect` directive. Use mod_rewrite instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)prod_id=100(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^detail\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new-url/? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{THE_REQUEST} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks but it appears to conflict with the existing code. Here is what I currently have.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Try posting your code by editing your question since its not readable from comments.

Comment: Also provide some brief summary what your existing rules are doing?

Comment: Ok anubhava I have edited the original post so that the code shows clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide some brief summary what your existing rules are doing?

Comment: To be honest I've no idea. This is a remnant from and old web developer. I'm in the process of changing my old site to a new wordpress site so all of the urls have changed from product ID urls to more readable urls. When the new site goes live I'll be replacing the .htaccess file with the one made by wordpress but I'll need to manually add in the 301 redirects for each url. I thought I'd be able to test them in this one before I go live.

Comment: You sir are a genius. It worked perfectly. So for each url I need two lines of code? The condition (which has the product ID) and the rule which has the new url?

Comment: One last question, for standard .html urls which don't have variables, shall I just place this at the top of the .htaccess file in the normal way as shown at the top of this post?

Comment: Hi anubhava, I had a little trouble getting that code to work in the default .htaccess created by wordpress. It killed the site when I used the previous working version. Is there a way to combine the two? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See updated code. I have combined previous code with your WP code. Replace your WP .htaccess with above and test. **Also make sure in WP permalink settings you have `www.domain.com`**

Comment: Glad to know, Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.